# ActiveRecord: how to do nested queries on foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models, "Coach", "Team", and "Event"

An event has attributes away_team and home_team, both of which belong to Team. A team belongs to a coach, and a coach can have many teams.

What I'd like to do is find all events where the home_team is not coached by a particular coach. So, something along the lines of:

```
Event.where("home_team.team.coach_id NOT ?", coach.id)
```

The problem is figuring out how to write up that syntax. I'm guessing I need to include the "team" model, but I'm not sure how to write an activerecord include that joins through a specific foreign key.

In short, any ideas on how to do this without getting SQL errors (which I've had countless of tonight) would be very appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need this kind of sql:

```
SELECT events.* FROM events JOIN team on events.home_team_id = teams.id WHERE teams.coach_id != coach_id
```

so in rails it should looks something like that:

```
Event.joins("join teams on events.home_team_id = teams.id").where("teams.coach_id != ?", coach_id)
```

Of course I don't know your exact table namings, so you should fit this solution to your problem.

If you have in Event model association: belogns_to: home_team, you can use only joins(:home_team).where(....)